# Insert Firebase on React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am new on React Native, and learn to create a simple CRUD App.
I am using firebase as my storage , I follow a tutorial on this [site](https://www.positronx.io/create-react-native-firebase-crud-app-with-firestore/)` but when I try on insert statement my react app only showing slow preloader when I hit insert button

Here is my code **firebaseDb.js** :

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import firestore from 'firebase/firestore'

    const firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: "MY KEY",
      authDomain: "MY DOMAIN",
      databaseURL: "MY DB URL",
      projectId: "MY PROJECT ID",
      storageBucket: "STORAGE BUCKET",
      messagingSenderId: "SENDER ID",
      appId: "APP ID",
      measurementId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    };
  firebase.database.enableLogging(true);
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    firebase.firestore();

export default firebase;
```

and here is my source code on AddTodo.js file :

```
class AddTodo extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.dbRef = firebase.firestore().collection('todo');
    this.state = {
      task: '',
      isLoading: false
    };
  }

  inputValueUpdate = (val, prop) => {
    const state = this.state;
    state[prop] = val;
    this.setState(state);
  }

  storeTodo(){
    if(this.state.task === ''){
      alert('task is required !')
    }
    else {
      console.log(this.state.task);
      this.setState({
          isLoading: true,
      });      
      this.dbRef.add({
        task: this.state.task,
      }).then((res) => {
        console.error(res);
          this.setState({
            task: '',
            isLoading: false,
          });
          this.props.navigation.navigate('TodoList')
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error("Error found: ", err);
        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
        });
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    if(this.state.isLoading){
      return(
        <View style={styles.preloader}>
          <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#9E9E9E"/>
        </View>
      )
    }

    return (
     <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.inputGroup}>
        <TextInput
          placeholder={'Task'}
          value={this.state.task}
          onChangeText={(val) => this.inputValueUpdate(val,'task')}
        />

        <Button
          onPress={() => this.storeTodo() }
          title="Tambah Task"
          color="#19AC52"
        />
      </View>


     </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}
```

Also, on my firebase console, I've change the rules read and write as **TRUE** already and that didn't affected.

and after the preload showed, there was an error message like this :

> Setting a timer for a long period of time, i.e. multiple minutes, is a performance and correctness issue on Android as it keeps the timer module awake, and timers can only be called when the app is in the foreground. See https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12981 for more info.

Something went wrong with my code and any idea to solve this error ?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue couple of days ago, ended up using [React Native Firebase](https://rnfirebase.io) library cause I was not able to connect to Firestore using official firebase npm module in react native.

Its important to say that this library is recommended by google as seen on [this page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/libraries). And works pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

I stomped into this same warning recently, it's a bug between Firebase and React Native and it has been around since 2017

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/97

Editing a parameter in a node-modules file fixes the warning (https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/97#issuecomment-485410026) but it can have other problems associated and you have to make the same hotfix after each npm install.

I haven't tried React Native Firebase package, maybe it's a cleaner way to get rid of the problem.